# Spark 1.4.1 - Using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I tried using this command , I get error

**Code**

```
 instances = sqlContext.sql("SELECT instance_id ,instance_usage_code 
 FROM ib_instances WHERE (instance_usage_code) = 'OUT_OF_ENTERPRISE' ")

 instances.write.format("orc").save("instances2")

 hivectx.sql(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instances2 (instance_id 
 string, instance_usage_code STRING)""" )

 hivectx.sql (" LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hduser/instances2' into 
 table instances2 ")
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/home/hduser/spark_script.py", line 57, in 
>   instances.write.format("orc").save("instances2") File 
>   "/usr/local/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/s
>   ql/readwriter.py", line 304, in save File 
>   "/usr/local/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/
>   py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in **call** File 
>   "/usr/local/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/
>   py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.save.
>   : java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: The ORC data source can
>   only be used with HiveContext. at
>   scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179) at 
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.DefaultSource.createRelation(OrcRelation
>   .scala:54) at 
>   org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:322)
>   at 
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:144)
>   at 
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:135)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.j
>   ava:57) at 
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccess
>   orImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231) at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379) at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259) at 
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you create a standard SQLContext, instead of a Hive one (that adds a couple of options). Create your sqlContext as a HiveContext instance. The scala version is:

```
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
```